# Design Progressbar like a rpg health bar

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-progressbar

I'm currently working on a health bar for my app and already got it to this  using a progressbar:
[image]

with this progressDrawable:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="5dip" />
        <solid android:color="#212121" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="5dip" />
            <solid android:color="#4CAF50"/>
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```

Now i want something like this:
[image]

But I have no idea how to get a background like this with the curve on the top and the orange line outside of it. 
How could I do this?

Comment: A `HealthBarView extends ProgressBar` would be a decent start.

Comment: Paint a new image that contains the orange corner and the HP letters which has a transparent area inside. Paint it over the progress bar. Then write something that displays the number and paints it over both other images.

Comment: Or create a custom view with a custom background image and progressbar.